# HTML showing as text

Tags: 8

i am using below code to show content in admincontroller of my module but $filelink is show as text instead of html

i tried to show href link in $filelink but it renders and text content like below:

```
<a href='abc/pdf_2.pdf' target='_blank'>Resume</a>
```

but i want it as

[Resume](http://abc/pdf_2.pdf)

```
  function content() {
    $url = Url::fromRoute('bd_career_add');
    //$add_link = ;
    $add_link = '<p>' . \Drupal::l(t('New Submission'), $url) . '</p>';

    $text = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $add_link,
    );

    // Table header.
    $header = array(
      'id' => t('Id'),
      'name' => t('Name'),
      'number' => t('Number'),
      'email' => t('Email'),
      'email' => t('Resume'),
      'operations' => t('Delete'),
    );
    $rows = array();
    foreach (BdCareerStorage::getAll() as $id => $content) {
      // Row with attributes on the row and some of its cells.
      $editUrl = Url::fromRoute('bd_career_edit', array('id' => $id));
      $deleteUrl = Url::fromRoute('bd_career_delete', array('id' => $id));

    $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($content->resumefid);
    $filelink ="<a href='".file_create_url($file->getFileUri())."' target='_blank'>Resume</a>";

      $rows[] = array(
        'data' => array(
          \Drupal::l($id, $editUrl),
          $content->name.' '.$content->lname,$content->number,$filelink,
          \Drupal::l('Delete', $deleteUrl)
        ),
      );
    }
    $table = array(
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $rows,
      '#attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'bd-career-table',
      ),
    );
    //return $add_link . ($table);
    return array(
      $text,
      $table,
    );
  }
```

Comment: try this : $row[] = array( 'data' => array(    '#links' => $links), );

Comment: whats the output

Comment: i used '#links' => $filelinkin place of $filelink it show blank value

Answer (score 0):

solved it using below code:

```
$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($content->resumefid);
$filelink = file_create_url($file->getFileUri());

$url = Url::fromUri($filelink);
$external_link = \Drupal::l(t('Download Resume'), $url);

  $rows[] = array(
    'data' => array(
      \Drupal::l($id, $editUrl),
      $content->name.' '.$content->lname,$content->number,$external_link,
      \Drupal::l('Delete', $deleteUrl)
    ),
```